UINavigationBar title "bounces" when switching UITabBarController tabs
I'm experiencing a strange issue only on iOS 18 with navigation bar titles (large and normal).
When switching between tabs in a UITabBarController, the title briefly bounces/jumps by a few pixels before settling in its final position. I checked and it's reproducible only on iOS 18, on iOS 17 everything seems perfect.
I created an empty project and the problem is there too. If needed I can upload it.
Setup:

Add a UITabBarController in the storyboard
Each tab's UIViewController is wrapped in its own UINavigationController
Set a title in the UIViewController

Run, you'll see the title jumping / glitching a little. It's more evident if the navigation bar is opaque.
I know it's a small issue but it's so obnoxious!

I am also facing the same issue and I believe it might be related to iOS 18 itself. Also have you created new app with minimum target iOS 17 and Xcode 16? (Because that is my case)
